# Spring crud repository sorting by case insensitive string

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

My interface for the crud repository is:

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<BookEntity, String> {

    List<BookEntity> findByLibraryIdOrderByNumberAsc(long libraryId);
}
```

I would like to get a list of book entities by the id of the library where they are located, but also sort by some field called number, which is a string (as it might look like 'ISBN-12356') , and sort in ascending order, but the order should be also case insensitive.

I assume this can be done in SQL using

```
select * from Books where libraryId = ?  order by lower(number) ASC
```

Is there any equivalent to this in Spring Crud repsoitory which can be achieved by using method names , with no specific definition of native SQL involved?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: To make sure I got it right, you want to achieve this functionality with out using any `Query` annotation and just with the method name convention? And with `findByLibraryIdOrderByNumberAsc` you are able to get the result but it is resulting in a case sensitive search instead? And you want it to be case insensitive. Is it?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you'll need to create JPQL query:

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<BookEntity, String> {

    @Query("select books from BookEntity books where libraryId = ?1  order by lower(number) ASC")
    List<BookEntity> findByLibraryIdOrderByNumberAsc(long libraryId);
}
```

Comment: I will upvote because the solution exposes only the required parameter by the "business logic", whereas the solution i decided to use, expects to get a sort object.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found is using the following:

```
 List<BookEntity> findByBookId(long libraryId, Sort sort);
```

And then in order to use this method, you can use a sort object that looks like this:

```
public static final Sort SORT_BY_NUMBER = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "number").ignoreCase());
```